# Simultaneous connections to single browser through PHP and Apache2

Tags: php, performance, apache, session

I have at the moment an AJAX request going to sendMail.php, it closes the connection immediately(using the header *Connection: Close*) and continues processing for approx 30 seconds.

But the problem I'm experincing now is that when that same client trys to load any PHP page from that server, it has to wait until sendMail.php has finished processing.

**Is there any way around this?**

I was reading on some other SO questions that it may be session related, but I'm not using any sessions, I even tried calling **session_write_close()** at the start of the sendMail.php script.

Example code (this is hacky and over done, but it works):

```
   //File: SendMail.php
   //error_reporting(E_ALL);
    error_reporting(0);
    session_write_close();
    set_time_limit(0); 
    ignore_user_abort(1);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    ini_set('ignore_user_abort','1');
    apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
    apache_setenv('KeepAlive',0);
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
    ini_set('output_buffering', 0);

    $size = ob_get_length();

    // send headers to tell the browser to close the connection
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    header('Connection: Close');
        // flush all output
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(30);//The real code has more stuff, but just for example lets just say it sleeps for 30 seconds
```

The rest of the referenced material is a normal navigation via GET.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous (that's what the first A stands for), so it shouldn't block other activity by the browser.

Comment: The AJAX completes successfully (response code 4, http 200 ok). As the connection is forcefully closed to the browser the PHP script continues, but other incomming responses from that browser (ie, navigating to the next page), get delayed until the first PHP script(sendMail.php) stops. The problem is that that particular script takes a  long time, and im circumnavigating that with AJAX and a force close of HTTP, but then PHP stops processing for that user until that initial AJAX request actually completes

Comment: The "Connection: close" header doesn't cause the connection to be closed. It just tells the browser not to try to reuse the connection for additional requests. PHP doesn't have any control over the connection itself, that's handled by the web server; it closes the connection when the script exits.  I'm at a loss to explain why one long-running PHP process will delay new connections to the server, though. Can you use a packet sniffer to see if the browser is trying to use the same connection instead of a new one?

Comment: How do I test for that? Also, looking at the headers Keep-Alive is turned on. Would that cause issues with it trying to regain that connection possibly?

Comment: I find that whenever you have a large script to run that takes a lot of processing, you should place it in you cronjobs.
In a way that instead of calling the script directly, you set a flag that says, run the script with the following parameters.
Then, on the cron, you read that flag and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like your AJAX call is calling a script that is chewing up your available resources on the server (whether that be memory/CPU/Disk I/O/etc) and that is preventing any new scripts from being able to run.  Double check to make sure that you have enough resources allocated to get the job done.

On a side note, typically you don't allow your everyday user to spawn processes that run that long on the server simply because you're opening up the opportunity for them to overload your system and give them an easy opportunity for a DDOS attack.  I'd consider Ibere's suggestion of moving this to a cron if that's a possibility.